# Network connection into a Faraday cage

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11

I have a situation where I need to put a WiFi-only IoT device inside a radiation-shielded space in which the facility WiFi doesn't work. (Even outside the shielded space the WiFi barely works, due, I think, to interference from various high-energy devices.)

Outside the shield, though, wired Ethernet works fine.  My question is, is there a WiFi gadget I can put in the shielded space and connected with an Ethernet cable running through a tunnel to the facility network?

Someone suggested a router, but I need to have the IoT device visible/discoverable on the facility network, so I think I can't use router DHCP and have to have the router just relay to/from the facility DHCP, whatever/wherever that is.  Someone else suggested a thing called a bridge, but apparently that's the reverse of what I need, connecting network WiFi to device wire rather than network wire to device WiFi.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of a WiFi Access Point? A cheap home wifi router can do what you need; set the LAN interface to something that won't interfere, and turn off the DHCP server., use only the LAN ports. (bridging is a bidirectional process) Note: it's not a true faraday cage if there are wires crossing it.

Comment: Copper cabling, such as that commonly used for ethernet, is also an antenna along the entire length of the cable, so extending that into a Faraday cage defeats the purpose of the cage.

Answer (score 1):

A wireless access point (WAP) bridges between Ethernet and Wi-Fi and is what you need.

You could use most consumer-grade wireless routers as well (off topic here though), but if you connect it via the WAN port you've likely got a NAT router. Instead, use a LAN port for the uplink, and disable DHCP and any discovery features like UPnP. Make sure that the router properly bridges between wired and wireless.

A wireless link inside a Faraday cage could be problematic due to reflections. It might be necessary to tune the link somewhat - vary the distance between WAP and end node, adjust antennas or transmission power.